# Elasticbeanstalk npm: command not found

Tags: npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My project was working since 2 years with no problem.
But this morning, It becomes to return error.

```
sudo: npm: command not found
```

Here's my .ebextensions file
I'm using Amazon Linux 2 with PHP.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root

  # Point the app root to the public/ folder.
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: document_root
    value: /p

    ublic
    
      # Set here your php.ini `memory_limit` value.
      - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
        option_name: memory_limit
        value: 256M
    
    container_commands:
      00_copy_env_file:
        command: "mv /tmp/.env /var/app/staging/.env"
      01_install_composer_dependencies:
        command: "sudo php /usr/bin/composer.phar install --no-dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader"
        cwd: "/var/app/staging"
    
      02_install_node_dependencies:
        command: "sudo npm install"
        cwd: "/var/app/staging"
    
      03_build_node_assets:
        command: "npm run dev"
        cwd: "/var/app/staging"
    
      04_link_storage_folder:
        command: "php artisan storage:link"
        cwd: "/var/app/staging"
    
      05_run_migrations:
        command: "php artisan migrate --force"
        cwd: "/var/app/staging"
        leader_only: true
    
      06_run_migrations:
        command: "php artisan key:generate"
        cwd: "/var/app/staging"
    
      07_run_migrations:
        command: "php artisan passport:install"
        cwd: "/var/app/staging"
```

What's change on elasticbeanstalk on AWS. Whats wrong with my configuration?

All my websites are down at the same time, this morning.

edit:

.platform/hooks/prebuild/install_latest_node_js.sh file is below.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Install Latest Node

# Some Laravel apps need Node & NPM for the frontend assets.
# This script installs the latest Node 12.x alongside
# with the paired NPM release.

sudo yum remove -y nodejs npm

sudo rm -fr /var/cache/yum/*

sudo yum clean all

curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -

sudo yum install nodejs -y

# Uncomment this line and edit the Version of NPM
# you want to install instead of the default one.
# npm i -g npm@6.14.4
```

Comment: How did you install `npm` before?

Comment: I got, curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash - code, inside .platform/hooks/prebuild folder.

Comment: Can you ssh to the EB instance and check if its still installed?

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```